# Why won't this hashing program print the non-hashed text and then the hashed version?

Tags: python

I just made a program where any text you put will spit back a text that is hashed. However, the program doesn't print the non-hashed text and then doesn't hash the real text.

```
import hashlib

not_hashed = []
hashed = []
while True:
    word_hash = input("Hello this is a python string convertor.\n"
                      "Any thing you say will be encoded using hashes\n"
                      "What is your message: ")
    hashed.append(word_hash)
    hash_object = hashlib.md5(word_hash.encode())
    hashed.append(hash_object)
    print("This is your message")
    print("Not hashed: ")
    print(not_hashed)
    print("Hashed")
    print(hashed)
```

Comment: Is `hashed.append(word_hash)` supposed to be `not_hashed.append(word_hash)`?

Answer (score 0):

Two changes are required. See the commented lines:

```
import hashlib

not_hashed = []
hashed = []
while True:
    word_hash = raw_input("Hello this is a python string convertor.\nAny thing you say will be encoded using hashes\nWhat is your message: ")
    not_hashed.append(word_hash) #Needs to append to 'not_hashed' rather than 'hashed'
    hash_object = hashlib.md5(word_hash.encode())
    hashed.append(hash_object.hexdigest()) #The md5 is a binary object 'hexdigest' will give you a human readable object
    print("This is your message")
    print("Not hashed: ")
    print(not_hashed)
    print("Hashed")
    print(hashed)
```